# Google api version version 25 is giving followin error: Error: 'valueInputOption' is required but not specified

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Although I am specifying valueInputoption but still i am getting this error. I followed google sheet`s quickstart.js tutorial for authentication.

```
  function appendData(auth) {

    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
    values: [ ["Void", "Canvas", "Website"], ["Paul", "Shan", "Human"] ];

     var body = {
    values: this.values
   };
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
   auth: auth,
   spreadsheetId: '13QPQj1Ot0oBJms2eQzrKahwzGt13JxQkqf54j2zk3jI',
   range: 'Sheet1!A2:B', //Change Sheet1 if your worksheet's name is 
   //something else
   valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
   insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
  resource: body

      }, (err, response) => {
   if (err) {
  console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  return;
} else {
    console.log("Appended");
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might be an issue with v^25.0. Switching to v24.0.0 resolved the issue for me:

`...
"dependencies": {
        "googleapis": "24.0.0",
      },
...`

https://gist.github.com/iaincollins/43302ea047d4a77e6605350598d160c1

Comment: I forgot to update but yes this was the issue I used the previous version and code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I suggest that you change is to use apostrophe (') instead of double quotes ("). If that doesn't work check my snippet taken from [Sheets API NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) combining it with the concepts of [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#InsertDataOption):

```
function appendToSheet(auth) {
    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      auth: auth,
      spreadsheetId: 'MY_SPREADSHEET_ID',
      range: 'rawSheet!A:B',
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
      resource: {
          "range": "rawSheet!A:B",
          "values": [
             [ "Conor","McGregor"]
          ]
      }
    });
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey its a bug in latest version, code is working fine with previous version and highly appreciate the reply :)