# Something wrong in update my data via Google Sheets API

Tags: node.js, post, google-sheets, google-api, updates

I want to Update my Google sheets data via Google Sheets API.
It look like connect to Google's server and send request successful.
But my Google sheets data was not update.
And the response:result.updatedCells is undefined.
Where did I go wrong?

```
function listMajors(auth) {
    var body = {
        values: [["2"]]
    };
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        spreadsheetId: '{MyGoogleSheetsId}',
        range: "table2!K2"+"?valueInputOption=RAW",
        majorDimension:'ROWS',
        auth: auth,
        resource: body
    }, function(err, result) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else 
            console.log('updateRange: '+result.updatedRange);
            console.log('updatedCells: '+result.updatedCells);
            console.log('updatedRows '+result.updatedRows);
        });
    }
}
```

[Value of response of range is OK, but response of other is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnOep.png)
Although server had received my request.
My Google sheets still not update.

Comment: Thank you everyone to read my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please put the property of `majorDimension` to the resource object.
- Please modify `range: "table2!K2"+"?valueInputOption=RAW",`
- You can retrieve the result by `result.data`.

#### Modified script:

```
function listMajors(auth) {
  var body = {
    majorDimension: "ROWS", // Added
    values: [["2"]],
  };
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: '{MyGoogleSheetsId}',
    range: "table2!K2", // Modified
    valueInputOption: "RAW", // Modified
    auth: auth,
    resource: body,
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // or console.log(err.errors);
      return;
    }
    console.log('updateRange: '+result.data.updatedRange); // Modified
    console.log('updatedCells: '+result.data.updatedCells); // Modified
    console.log('updatedRows '+result.data.updatedRows); // Modified
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes the following points.

  - Your environment can update the spreadsheet using Sheets API.
  - `sheets` is declared.
- If this didn't work, can you try it with the latest version of googleapis?

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

In my environment, I confirmed that this modified script worked. If this didn't work in your environment, I'm sorry.

### Edit:

In my environment, I confirmed that the modified script worked fine using googleapis of version 27.0.0 and the latest version (35.0.0). Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. So I would like to propose other method.

#### Sample script:

This script updates the spreadsheet using the method of values.update of Sheets API. This script uses `auth` of your script. When you use this script, please modify the script in `listMajors(auth)` to the following script.

```
function listMajors(auth) {
  const request = require('request');

  const spreadsheetId = '{MyGoogleSheetsId}';
  const range = "table2!K2";
  auth.getRequestHeaders()
  .then(function(e) {
    var body = {
      majorDimension: "ROWS",
      values: [["2"]],
    };
    var options = {
      uri: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${range}?valueInputOption=RAW`,
      method: "put",
      headers: e,
      json: body,
    };
    request(options, function(err, res, result){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply~~~

Comment: I have written " valueInputOption: "RAW", // Modified ",
but it was return an error : https://i.imgur.com/q4h2LJm.png
So I modified my program according this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213939/google-sheet-api-valueinputoption-is-required-but-not-specified

Comment: @黃翊唐 I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If this was not what you want, I'm sorry. By the way, if you want to retrieve the result using ``sheets.spreadsheets.values.update()``, please try to modify from ``result.updatedRange``, ``result.updatedCells`` and ``result.updatedRows`` to ``result.data.updatedRange``, ``result.data.updatedCells`` and ``result.data.updatedRows``, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much ! but this problem is still not solved. I give up to use Google API to updata my data. Maybe I will get/update data with myself DB server. Thanks you!!!

Comment: @黃翊唐 Thank you for replying and additional information. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.